# How to do the Smart Contract Storage Migration using Quorum?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, quorum

I wrote one smart contract without upgradable logic, now I want to update the same smart contract with some changes. Is it possible to copy the data from old contract storage to a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not going to be possible to upgrade the contract, but copying the values should be trivial. The node creating new contract should read the current state via contract accessors (if those exist), otherwise, scan the chain for contract calls to this contract and set value based on the inputs from that.